# Interaction of Magnetic field with light

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

Can there be any interaction of a varying magnetic field with light? (Please explain using electromagnetic waves as both are)

(Say we have an alternating current of 60Hz and He-Ne laser (632.8 nm wavelength) 
What all different kinds of interaction may happen? In free space or in a dielectric medium (Just an example for the sake of analysis))

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more details about the context of the situation. The magnetic field (as the electric fields) is light in a sense. They are fields made out of photons. For specific cases it might be useful to use certain effective description, but without more context is not possible...

Comment: The answer completely depends on the context: is this happening in vacuum? Or are you also considering interactions inside a material? If the former, the answer is no; if the latter, then the effect does exist, and it is known as the [Faraday effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%20effect).

Answer (score 2):

In matter, there is Faraday rotation.

In vacuum, hypothetical axions would also cause a rotation of the plane of polarization. Experiments have been done with superconducting magnets and ultra-high vacuum. This gave a zero-result, within experimental boundaries. (University of Rochester and Brookhaven)

Answer (score -1):

If you've wanted to mean the change of direction of the light beam by the word 'interaction' ,then the answer is no, because a photon of a light ray goes with a very high speed so if there will be a varying magnetic field then the work done by that varying magnetic field will be 0.

Comment: Light is an electro magnetic wave, also if we have an varying magnetic field which is also an electromagnetic wave, they have same speed which is c. I don't understand what you are getting at here. Please clarify.